# Transaction log for database records (batch updates)

Tags: .net, database, postgresql, synchronization, ios5

I will have several not-always-connected clients to a N-Tier app with a postgres backend.

Some of those clients could be some days behind the rest. This is for a point-of-sale setup.

My number of tables is low, only `customers, orders, orders_details, products, inventory` and some config tables.

I want to provide a reliable way to update devices when they connect to the main server, to replicate and apply changes.

I suspect a transaction log is the best way, but I don't know how do it.

I think of creating a table in both clients & server with:

```
OperationType | UserId | TimeStamp | Source | JsonData
```

But I don't know exactly how to proceed. Is there a sample implementation I can look at? I don't want a heavy, generic solution like the [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753). Also, I need to access the server from obj-c, python clients - the server is .net.

The clients need to operate stand-alone, so I can't reserve records.

Answer (score 0):

On PostgreSQL the best approach is probably to use Slony to handle the actual updates (allowing for an asynchronous/offline approach) and then differentiate between feeds of data in to the main server and authoritative information for the application purposes.  In this structure:

1. Each server has its own feed tables which it writes to, and it queries these along with the main data tables in the course of ordinary operations.
2. Each server replicates its feed tables to partitions of a main server's feed tables, and then this data is copied into the main tables using triggers, and replicated out to all clients.  The child databases (if we can call that) then truncate the feed tables after they can confirm that the replication has been successful both ways.